# UICollectionViewCell updating constraints after adjusting layout in code

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I am adjusting UILabels and an UIImageView's frame in code in UICollectionViewCell to fit smaller device sizes but I can't seem to scroll to the end of the UICollectionView. There are about two unreachable cells.

I suspect that it could be a constraints problem and I have tried calling updateConstraints or updateConstraints if needed but nothing visible seems to be happening.  I make use of AutoLayout in the storyboard.

Comment: do you change the UICollectionViewCell size to? by the way if you use auto layout y do you need to change the UIImageView and UILabels frame? let Auto Layout handle it for you..

Comment: yes I edit the cell size too. Autolayout doesn't scale my label and images inside the cell to how I want it to appear.

Comment: so something is wrong with your constrains, anyhow I will try to answer y the content size is to small in a few minutes..

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem, because you are changing the Cells at runtime, after the contentSize already as been calculated you need to set it manually.

Try to set the collectionViewContentSize manually and tell me if it worked..